# How can i see my echo prints on the heroku logs?

Tags: php, heroku

I have a free PHP heroku webapp that is running fine.
(sending push notifications).

When i print from within the PHP app like that:

```
echo 'sending push !!!' . PHP_EOL;
```

I don't see these prints on the heroku logs when i do

```
heroku --tail
```

any idea why ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You simply [write to `stderr`](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/logging#writing-to-your-log):

```
file_put_contents("php://stderr", "sending push !!!".PHP_EOL);
```

Or, if you're using Monolog:

```
use Monolog\Logger;
use Monolog\Handler\StreamHandler;

$log = new Logger('yourlogger');
$log->pushHandler(new StreamHandler('php://stderr', Logger::DEBUG));

$log->addNotice('sending push !!!');
```

Don't use a particular log file path, or `LOG_PATH`, that won't actually do anything.

Answer (score 0):

A echo'd string in PHP will not show up in the Heroku logs, what you need to do is create a seperate log file that holds all your logging. I don't know if you use any logging mechanism or even a PHP framework.

If you don't have any log mechanisms yet you can take a look at: https://github.com/Seldaek/monolog . It's a plug and play module for PHP to write out a log.

```
use Monolog\Logger;
use Monolog\Handler\StreamHandler;

// create a log channel
$log = new Logger('name');
$log->pushHandler(new StreamHandler('debug.log', Logger::WARNING));

// add records to the log
$log->addWarning('Foo');
$log->addError('Bar');
```

When that is installed, you can set a environment variable inside heroku to assign heroku to the log file.

```
heroku config:set LOG_PATH=/set/to/your/log/file
```

Hope this will help you further.

Comment: Thanx! is that the simplest way to do it ? cant i just write from PHP to stdout in a way that heroku will pick it up without external modules ?

Comment: If you rather don't want to use a logger you can persist the logs by 'fopen', 'fwrite' and 'fclose' @BenGoodwin

Comment: What is `LOG_PATH` supposed to do? That won't cause tailing of that log file automatically. It's also not the recommended approach. Heroku and 12factor has always been recommending logging to `stderr` (that's what it's for after all).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to log variables to heroku log, you can simply use the following.

```
$some_value=2;
file_put_contents("php://stderr", "$some_value\n");
```